# How to check between play/pause button images

Tags: iphone

Lets say I have image1 as`Play Icon.png`and image2 as `pause.png`.

I want to do something like this, if the buttons image is image1 do this and if buttons image is image2 do that.

```
[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

how do i find out wheter its `Play Icon.png or pause.png`.

Thanks

Comment: Don't check for the image, check for the selected state. a `UIButton` has a property called `selected` that you can use to get / set the button state, which will in turn change the icon to the image you have assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't easily determine what image is inside your "`UIButton`" but since you're setting that image by state, just check the [*state* property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/state)  of the button.

Then you'll know which image you are using.

It can be as easy as:

```
if( playpauseButton.state == UIControlStateSelected )
    NSLog( @"Here I am using pause.png");
```

or, if you're doing this inside an action:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPushed: (id) sender
{
    UIButton * theButton = (UIButton *) sender;
    if(theButton)
    {
        if( theButton.state == UIControlStateSelected )
            NSLog( @"Here I am using pause.png");
    }
}
```